# necessary to remove event handlers by hand?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Morning,

When using `Element#observe()`, is it necessary to call `Element#stopObserving()` to completely get rid of the event handler?
Or will some inbuilt mechanism realize that the handler is no longer necessary when the Element gets removed in any way (`.update()` on a parent, not just `.remove()`) ?

Updating large dynamic lists with several bindings per entry every now and then. Drawbacks when using something like

```
ul.update(''); data.each(..
ul.insert(X); X.bind(..);  ..);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If an element is no longer part of the DOM then garbage collection will probably deal with it's handlers, but that will depend on the browser.

I would suggest you not worry about what is out of your control and look at using [`Event.on()`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/on/) instead.